# ListBox with Dictionary data source displays full KeyValuePair instead of just value

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, listbox, datasource

I have a listbox with a `Dictionary<int, UmfTag>` as its DataSource. I have set the listbox's DisplayMember to "Value" and ValueMember to "Key," but the when the listbox is displayed, it shows all the KeyValuePairs instead of just the value.

My code:

```
listBoxAllTags.DataSource = new BindingSource(punchedTagDict, null);
listBoxAllTags.DisplayMember = "Value";
listBoxAllTags.ValueMember = "Key";
```

The Value in each KeyValuePair is my custom object UmfTag. It contains, among other properties, an ID and a Description. UmfTag's ToString() method returns `String.Format("{0:D4} - {1}", Id, Description)`. For example, for a UmfTag with `Id = 12` and `Description = "Name"`, the Value would be displayed as

`0012 - Name`

That above is what I want in my listbox. Unfortunately, for some reason, the listbox displays the entire KeyValuePair instead of just the Value, so it instead displays

`[12, 0012 - Name]`

As you can see from my code, I'm explicitly setting the DisplayMember to "Value." So why is that not working? I tried converting my `Dictionary<int, UmfTag>` to a `List<KeyValuePair<int, UmfTag>>`, but the problem persists.

I *can* convert the Dictionary into a `List<UmfTag>` and ignore the Key (since the Key is the Id in the UmfTag itself), but I want to keep this collection as a Dictionary. If I have to, I can just rebuild the Dictionary from the List, but that seems inefficient.

I must be doing something wrong, but my code appears to be identical to all the other topics on using Dictionaries and DataSources, so what's my problem?

**EDIT:**
Because I needed to bold and italicize certain items in the list, I wrote my own DrawListBox method which is called whenever listBoxAllTags_DrawItem is called. Here is my method:

```
private void DrawListBox(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e, ListBox listBox, Dictionary<int, UmfTag> searchedDict)
{
    if(e.Index < 0) return;

    e.DrawBackground();
    FontStyle fontStyle = FontStyle.Regular;
    Brush brush = Brushes.Black;

    // Embolden the first x items, where x = the number of searched results
    if(e.Index < searchedDict.Count)
        fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;

    // Make the selected item have white font (so you can see it over the blue background)
    if((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        brush = Brushes.White;

    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), new Font("Arial", 8, fontStyle), brush, e.Bounds);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

I put a breakpoint in this method and investigated the value of the first parameter to the `e.Graphics.DrawString` call, `listBox.Items[e.Index].ToString()`. This value is the full KeyValuePair. I don't know why that is, but I think I just need to change that line of code to get the Item's Value property.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to my listBoxAllTags_DrawItem method. I had forgotten I had written my own DrawItem method because I needed some items to be bold and italicized. The problem most certainly resides there.

Comment: You should always use `GetItemText` method to get text of an item.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: That was the answer! I changed `listBox.Items[e.Index].ToString()` to `listBox.GetItemText(listBox.Items[e.Index])` and it worked perfectly. It's a little verbose for my taste, but if it works, I won't complain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get text of an item in `ComboBox` and `ListBox` you should always use [`GetItemText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

The method checks if the `DisplayMember` property of `ComboBox` is set, then it returns the string representation of the member specified in the `DisplayMember` property for the object that you passed to the method, otherwise it returns `ToString` of the object.

```
var txt = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.Items[e.Index]);
```